# How to create table structure in Android programmatically not in xml file

Tags: android

I am creating an Android app for online shopping. I just want to generate invoice after payment in table format programmatically. Please guide me to create a table view in java program of Android.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is not acceptable, since it is too broad and generic. This is not a tutorial site or a "gimme teh codez" one. You must show your efforts in coding and teh specific error you get. An eCommerce site is a way too broad subject.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is how you create a Table Layout Programmatically for both Linear Layout and Relative Layout :

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

1) Linear Layout

TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(context);
tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(context);
tableRow.setLayoutParams(tableParams);

TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
tableRow.addView(textView);

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

2) Relative Layout

TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(context);
tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new Relative.LayoutParams(Relative.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Relative.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(context);
tableRow.setLayoutParams(tableParams);

TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
tableRow.addView(textView);

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please don't encourage asking such questions by answering them.